# AngularFireStorage - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefine only in prod

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

When I use AngularFireStorage, I get this error when I am in `ng build --prod`, no errors in dev (`ng build`):
[image]

```
main.8afd3376565525d9bdde.bundle.js:1 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at e.project (main.8afd3376565525d9bdde.bundle.js:1)
    at e._next (main.8afd3376565525d9bdde.bundle.js:1)
    at e.next (main.8afd3376565525d9bdde.bundle.js:1)
    at e._next (main.8afd3376565525d9bdde.bundle.js:1)
```

#### Version info

Angular: 5.1.0
Firebase:4.9.0
AngularFire: 5.0.0-rc.6
zone.js: 0.8.19
node: 8.3.0,

#### How to reproduce:

I am using the official doc to upload a doc. (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <input type="file" (onchange)="uploadFile($event)">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
  }
}
```

and I have import `AngularFireStorageModule` in the main module

```
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
```

Error is from AngularFireStorage because when I do not import AngularFireStorage, I do not have the error.

```
constructor(
    // private storage: AngularFireStorage
) { }
```

FYI, here you have where the code is blocked. 
[image]

Comment: Please add the errors and code as text instead of images. This makes it searchable and it can be used in a possible answer.

Comment: error code has been added